# Setting Selenium WebDriver with Perl

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a sample script using perl for Selenium WebDriver. I have downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar file and I am executing following code:

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Test::More qw( no_plan ) ;
my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver();

$driver->get("http://www.google.com");
$driver->find_element('q','name')->send_keys("Hello WebDriver!");
ok($driver->get_title =~ /Google/,"title matches google");
$driver->quit();
```

but for this code to work I have to start java server using following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar
```

Do I have to explicitly start the server to run the script? Or, there is something else I can do like setting environment variable etc. so that I don't have to start the server like in java we don't explicitly start the server.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CHOWES/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.16/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm) clearly states:

> To use this module, you need to have already downloaded and started
>   the Selenium Server (Selenium Server is a Java application).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use any of the "unofficial bindings" (like the Perl bindings) you need to first launch the standalone-server jar file. As well, you need to do this in all the bindings if the browser is opening in a machine other than where the script is running (e.g. using RemoteWebdriver).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this, so you don't have to start the Selenium Server yourself:

```
`use Selenium::PhantomJS;`

`my $driver = Selenium::PhantomJS->new;`
```